# Lambda abstraction notation

Tags: haskell

I have seen the lambda abstraction notation in various academic papers that use TeX to convert Haskell notation to proper arrows and Greek lambdas and so on rendered as

```
λx.t
```

rather than

```
λx -> t
```

The first way is from the lambda calculus proper, and the latter is current Haskell language syntax.

Is it considered proper to use the formal lambda calculus style of notation when writing papers on Haskell now?

Comment: I'd say it depends on intented audience. If you're writing maths, use mathematical notation. If you want it to be cross-language, ditto. If you're writing a paper on Haskell, use Haskell notation.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, both a dot and an arrow are acceptable mathematical notations; just be _consistent_ with which one you use. (This is similar to writing exp(x) verses e^x. Either is fine; just be consistent.)

Answer (score 4):

#### Well, ...

... that's a hard question to answer. At the very least it can be confusing, so, whenever you do it, you probably don't want to use `.` to denote function composition anymore, as in (admittedly, somewhat contrived)

```
(>>>) = λf. λg. g . f
```

Instead, you may then want to typeset this as, for example

```
(>>>) = λf. λg. g ∘ f
```

#### Personally, ...

... just to avoid the confusing, I generally prefer

```
(>>>) :: ∀α. ∀β. ∀γ. (α → β) → (β → γ) → α → γ
(>>>) =  λf → λg → g ∘ f
```

with a nicely styled arrow for the lambda-binders, dots for the forall-binders, and circles for function-composition operators.

By the way: [lhs2TeX](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lhs2tex) is a great tool for doing this kind of typesetting.